# ternary operator with .map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

I'm working on a project in React which uses an external api. In this api sometimes a value from object that is returned inside an array will = null which is fine however it then makes the data I'm displaying look ugly.

for instance

```
              {res?.tv_credits.cast
              .filter((items, idx) => idx < 10)
              .map((item) => {
                return (
                  <SwiperSlide>
                    <div className="card" key={item.id}>
                      <Link to={`/TvPage/${item.id}`} className="linkName">
                        <img
                          src={
                            `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/` +
                            item.poster_path
                          }
                          alt="movie poster"
                        />
                      </Link>
                    </div>
```

the api looks something like this

[image: Array details]

you can see in object 3 the "poster path returns null.

So what I'm trying to do here is on any array that is mapped through were a value returns as null, a specified image is going to be displayed instead of the movie poster I've tried a few different ways I can think of in using a ternary operator to check if the path is equal to null however it doesn't seem to work.

```
                  <img
                    src={
                      `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/` +
                        item.poster_path == null ? photo : 
                       `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/` + item.poster_path
                          }
                          alt="movie poster"
                        />
```

in this instance here the other images display fine but the ones that do equal null still show nothing.

I did notice that when inspecting the one returning null in the console it shows a path of https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/null

I did try to check for this as well like

```
             <img
                    src={
                      `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/` +
                        item.poster_path == https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/null ? photo : 
                       `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/` + item.poster_path
                          }
                          alt="movie poster"
                        />
```

so for fun I decided to try

```
                  <img
                    src={
                      `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/` +
                        item.poster_path !== null ? photo : 
                       `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/` + item.poster_path
                          }
                          alt="movie poster"
                        />
```

this in turn makes all the items that are returned show the photo and not the movie poster.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: side topic. use `arr.slice(0, 10)` instead of `arr.filter((value, index) => index < 10)`

Comment: Shouldn't your condition be just `item.poster_path == null ? photo : 
                       \`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/\` + item.poster_path` ?

Comment: @mulan Thanks for the tip I'll make some updates!

Comment: @HassanImam Yeah, this is why i use stackoverflow I've been so focused on the issue I didnt step back and just think about it. This is correct. I should have been checking for the value of the item.poster_path first then appending the base url based on the condition. thanks. aspiring dev brain deadness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because of the operator precedence, in

```
`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/` + item.poster_path !== null ? optionA : option B
```

the left side will always evaluate to "not null" (`+` has higher precedence than `!==`), nothing that a simple pair of `()` won't fix:

```
https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/` + (item.poster_path !== null ? optionA : optionB)
```

(Though the template gets a little hard to read with all that detailed logic inside, why not make the image a small simple component taking `item` as a prop? Leave sth like

```
.map((item) => (
  <SwiperSlide>
    <div className="card" key={item.id}>
        <Link to={`/TvPage/${item.id}`} className="linkName">
            <MovieImage film="item" />
        </Link>
    </div>
  </SwiperSlide>)
```

Comment: I do appreciate the response thank you and honestly yeah I do need to refactor quite a bit of the entire app at some point because it is starting to get bloated I'm just trying to get things to work still haha

Answer (score 2):

If your ternary operation is like this:

```
https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ + 
   item.poster_path == null ? 
       photo : 
       https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ + item.poster_path
```

it basically means that when the `item.poster_path` is NOT `null` you are appending the entire text like this

`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ + https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ + item.poster_path`

Which I doubt will yield a correct URL for it.

Instead, try

```
https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ + 
   (item.poster_path != null? item.poster_path : photo)
```